# Align Center not aligning to page center in ArcGIS Pro after including margins from printer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, text-element

After using the **Include margins from printer** option of ArcGIS Pro to display printer margins on a layout, the Align Center option stops aligning to the center of the page and aligns to the left printer margin instead.

To see this try the following using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.2:

1. Start ArcGIS Pro
2. From its Start Page use **Start without a template**
3. Insert a New Layout - I chose **A4** from the **ISO - Portrait** category
4. Use the **Straight text** tool to drag a rectangle in a similar position to that in the picture below

[image]

5. Click on the page, away from the text, so that the text element handles can be seen
6. On the **Text | Format** tab of the ribbon, use the **Align** split button from the **Arrange** button group to first **Align to Page**, and then **Align Center**.  You should see the text move to the horizontal center of the page, which is to be expected.
7. Use the **Undo** button on the Quick Access Toolbar to move the text back to its previous position
8. Use the Layout tab of the ribbon to click on the **Select Page From Printer** button in the Page Setup button group (see picture below).  I am doing this because I want to display the printable area on my page.

[image]

9. Tick the **Include margins from printer** checkbox, and then **OK**.  You should see dashed lines appear just inside the page border to show the printable area of the page
10. Use the **Text | Format** tab of the ribbon again, to click **Align Center** again.  This time you should see the text move to be aligned with the left print margin (see picture below), which is NOT expected.

[image]

I believe this to be a bug, which I will report to Esri's local support.

While awaiting a fix for it, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to workaround this bug by doing the following:

1. On the Layout tab of the ribbon, I clicked the **Size** button in the **Page Setup** button group (see picture below) and chose a different page size.  I think any would do but I chose A3 under ISO Sizes.  The printer margins disappeared from the page.

[image]

2. I used the **Size** button again to choose my original page size which was A4 under ISO Sizes
3. I used the **Text | Format** tab of the ribbon to choose **Align Center** again.  This time the Text centered horizontally on the page, which is what I wanted.

The workaround above removes the printer margins from the page and makes the alignment options resume working as expected.